# Take name of variable as input and output its value - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'd like to know if there is something Ruby that does something like this:

```
@my_var = "foo"
some_function_i_dont_know_name_of("@my_var")
 => "foo"
```

Comment: `eval("@my_var")` would also do.

Comment: eval could potentially be used for code injections, if the value of @my_var can be set from the outside. instance_variable_get is safer.

Comment: `eval` is evil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [`instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get). From the docs:

> Returns the value of the given instance variable, or `nil` if the instance variable is not set. The `@` part of the variable name should be included for regular instance variables. Throws a `NameError` exception if the supplied symbol is not valid as an instance variable name. String arguments are converted to symbols.
>
> ```
> class Fred
>   def initialize(p1, p2)
>     @a, @b = p1, p2
>   end
> end
> fred = Fred.new('cat', 99)
> fred.instance_variable_get(:@a)    #=> "cat"
> fred.instance_variable_get("@b")   #=> 99
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

```
@my_var = "foo"
instance_variable_get("@my_var")
 => "foo"
```